# Validate Uniqueness and Edit Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form.
Same form is used for creating and editing...

In my model

```
validate_uniqueness_of :empID
```

is present..
and in my form on updating, I get the error that empID is already taken..
Is there any way i can exclude this validation in editing..

Comment: why do you want to exclude that validation on edit? It does not seem too useful...

Comment: When you say you are using the same form for creating and for editing, are you using the exact same form, including the url and method, that it is hitting?

Comment: @TheChamp thing is in my edit form i have disabled the option to edit the id.. Since i want the id to be shown as disbaled in that page i cant remove those line for empID with a condition like if params[:action]==edit.. so hope this is the only solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply define that your validation should only come into effect on create

```
validates :empID, uniqueness: true, on: :create
```

Comment: When addressing that uniqueness is mandatory for a record I don't think limiting this to the create action is an answer at all.

Comment: good point, it does seem that there are some more flaws behind this logic. I asked why he needs this.

Answer (score 1):

"@TheChamp thing is in my edit form i have disabled the option to edit the id.. Since i want the id to be shown as disbaled in that page i cant remove those line for empID with a condition like if params[:action]==edit.. so hope this is the only solution.."

if all you want is for the empID not to be editable when the form is for an existing one... you can indeed check if the form is for editing and just display it like this:
(Assuming that the moel is in a variable called `my_model`)

```
# new_record? will only be true for a model that is being created, not edited
<% if my_model.new_record? %>
  <%= f.select :empID, options_go_here %>
<% else %>
  # don't display the field-here, instead just display the employee-info
  <%= my_model.emp.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your application is doing exactly what you are instructing it to do.

You validate the uniqueness of the empID attribute which is on conflict upon the update request. Instead of only passing the validation upon it's create action you should think your logic through:

- Is there any situation where multiple entries hold the same empID?
- Why should the empID be unique? is it a primary key?

From my point of view it looks like empID defines a relation between the record and an emp model? if so adjust the validation to make it functional:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :emp
  validates_presence_of :empID
end
```